# How to reference a variable in jsDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Say I have this function:

```js
function wrapInObject(key){
  const result = { [key]: key }
  return result
}
```

and I have this code:

```js
const a = wrapInObject("Yellow")
a.Yel.. // <--- as I'm writing, the intellisense shows "Yellow"
```

I want to get intellisense from the code editor I'm using about the return value of this object, so as soon as I write ***"Yel"*** the code editor will autocomplete and show me the option **"Yellow"** to choose.

How to write this logic in jsDoc?

I have tried the following, but I stopped because I didn't know how to complete this:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} key - the string to wrap inside an object
 * @returns { ??? }
*/
function wrapInObject(key){
  const result = { [key]: key }
  return result
}
```

Is there something like

```js
  @returns {result}
```

I don't want "Yellow" to be hard-coded, someone might input "Orange", or "Boy", or "House" or anything.

It should be dynamic, not static

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic type for this purpose

```
/**
 * @template {string} T
 */
function wrapInObject(/**@type {T}*/key) {
  const result = /**@type {{[k in T]: T}}*/({ [key]: key });
  return result;
}
```

You can also replace `{[k in T]: T}` on `Record<T,T>` if you want

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXApgWwA4BsCGTIG8DO8ATgJYB2A5gL6QAqUIw4AZgK5kDG8JA9mZAHcimVAEkyAeQBGAK0RcAFKBAIAnqkR5aVRgGtEqgJR4okDn0KQiifK3TxIAXkjK1GvLgDauyOToBdAC46Kh1gBVxIbwMgyH1VSCpDAG5Ta3hWIn5rW3tUqnBwIRFxaTlFAHJmHh4KlKLhMUlZeXgFCqlMIjrkoA)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://dev.to/shhdharmen/how-to-utilise-jsdoc-comment-tags-so-that-visual-studio-code-intellisense-works-great-3ho4) you can see great example of [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html):

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} wrappedObject
 * @property {string} Yellow
 */

/**
 * @return {wrappedObject} wrappedObject - {@link wrappedObject}
 */
function wrapInObject(key){
  const result = { [key]: key }
  return result
}
```

---

I have not tested this code yet

Comment:  you're hard-coding "Yellow", that's why I'm asking. I don't want "Yellow" to be hard-coded in JSDoc, it should be dynamic, someone might input "Orange", or "House". That's why my question isn't answered.

Comment: @Normal So that's like runtime specific values, you can't write it into documentation beforehand. Imagine that values will be coming from user input in remote server. How can your local interpreter know it?

Comment: I know, I can't answer this question because I don't know typescript, but I have used many packages written in typeScript, and people were donig my example above, for example redux toolkit, it can detect many things based on your input in your code

Comment: @Normal You can detect it if you would pass in always same structure object

Comment: this looks really complex :;(